# How to find classes having member variable SomeTO in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse nicely gives me object graph of "Is-A" or "Inheritance/Generisation/Specialization". relationship.
But Is there any quick way to find "Has-A" or "Composition" relationship graph for classes in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + H 
It will open Java Search window.
select Field in "Search For" panel.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the places where some class is used when you put cursor on class name in it's declaration line (`public class SomeClass {`) and press Ctrl+Shift+G

AFAIK there is no such nice graph like for Is-A relationship.

Comment: It gives me all references to class. In my project class is referred in hundreds of places. but the class is participating in few classes in composition relations. So doing this way is not feasible for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Digambar's suggestion or use the File Search tab (hit Ctrl+H), which performs a plain old text search. You can specify the files that are searched and the scope of the search (selected resource, workspace, etc)